# jQuery syntax issue on slideOut/In function

Tags: jquery, accordion, show-hide

I know this is easy, just drawing a blank.

If you look at this page (all JS/CSS is on the one page), http://dl.dropbox.com/u/904456/expander.html

You can see what I have. Basically I would like to do two things differently.

A.) I would only like to show the .module .caption for the .module hovered, not both of them when either is hovered.
B.) I would like to slideOut rather then simply .show() and slideIn rather then simply .hide() (on hover and unhover.)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".module .caption").hide();
  $(".module").hover(function() {
    $(".module .caption").show(); 
    },function() {
    $(".module .caption").hide();   
  });
});
```

And my markup looks like:

```
 <div class="module span-1">
      <div class="inside">HOVER</div><!-- end .inside -->
        <h1>TITLE</h1>
        <div class="caption">
          <p>Caption ipsum lorem dolor ipsum lorem dolor ipsum lorem dolor ipsum lorem dolor</p>
        </div><!-- end .caption -->
    </div><!-- end .module -->

 <div class="module span-2">
  <div class="caption">
          <p>Caption ipsum lorem dolor ipsum lorem dolor ipsum lorem dolor ipsum lorem dolor</p>
      </div><!-- end .caption -->
      <div class="inside">HOVER</div><!-- end .inside -->
        <h1>TITLE</h1>
    </div><!-- end. module -->
```

Would love some assistance! And if your feeling especially generous, an explanation on your method (for next time). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By calling `$(".module .caption").show();` you are showing all elements with the class `caption` inside an element with the class `module`. Instead, you want to use the element in question (the element that has been hovered), which you can reference using `$(this)`. Then, you simply do your toggling however you'd like. See the [jQuery effects API](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/) for your options. This is one way to get the desired effect:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $("div.module div.caption").hide();
  $("div.module").hover(function() {
     $(this).find("div.caption").slideDown(); 
   },function() {
     $(this).find("div.caption").slideUp();   
   });
 });
```

**Edit**: Rather than using a selector of the form `$('.className')`, it is generally better to use `$('tag.className')`, as this selector will use the native Javascript method `getElementsByTagName` rather than looping over all elements in the DOM looking for ones with the given class.